# An entity is retrieved without a mapped object or list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have entity

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "personal_detail_id")
    private PersonalDetail personalDetail;
}
```

after retrieving an Employee object from the database

```
    employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, 1L);

    Assert.assertEquals(employee.getPersonalDetail().getBirthPlace(), "New Jersey");
```

I get an exception

```
NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.jonki.hibernate.entity.Employee.getPersonalDetail()" because "employee" is null
```

because it did not automatically get the mapped object. It has the same error with mapped lists. How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe there is no `employee` with id `1L`?

Comment: Tests show that basic attributes are obtained without the mapped ones.

Comment: Which basic attributes? Maybe you should add more to your code showing then and the test used.